# Get dataframe rows with the latest timestamp (Spark structured streaming)

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have this dataframe :

```
+------+-------------------+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+
|brand |original_timestamp |weight     |arrival_timestamp       |features                |
+------+-------------------+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+
|BR1   |1632899456         |4.0        |2023-08-09 17:12:24.002 |{f1 -> 12, f2 -> 52}    |
|BR1   |1632899456         |4.0        |2023-08-09 17:14:24.002 |{f1 -> 42, f2 -> 12}    |
|BR1   |1632899456         |2.0        |2023-08-09 17:46:24.002 |{f1 -> 42, f2 -> 12}    |
|BR3   |1632899155         |2.0        |2023-08-09 17:14:24.002 |{f1 -> 72, f2 -> 50}    |
|BR3   |1632899155         |9.0        |2023-08-09 17:20:24.002 |{f1 -> 72, f2 -> 50}    |
```

I would like to get the latest "arrival_timestamp" for each combination of :
**brand, original_timestamp and features**.
This is the code I am using :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("brand","original_timestamp","features").orderBy(col("arrival_timestamp").desc)

df.withColumn("maxTS", first("arrival_timestamp").over(windowSpec))
  .select("*").where(col("maxTS") === col("arrival_timestamp"))
  .drop("maxTS")
  .show(false)
```

This is the output I am expecting :

```
+------+-------------------+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+
|brand |original_timestamp |weight     |arrival_timestamp       |features                |
+------+-------------------+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+
|BR1   |1632899456         |4.0        |2023-08-09 17:12:24.002 |{f1 -> 12, f2 -> 52}    |

|BR1   |1632899456         |2.0        |2023-08-09 17:46:24.002 |{f1 -> 42, f2 -> 12}    |

|BR3   |1632899155         |9.0        |2023-08-09 17:20:24.002 |{f1 -> 72, f2 -> 50}    |
```

However, I am getting such error :

**grouping/join/window partition keys cannot be map type.**

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: grouping/join/window partition keys cannot be map type.**

And that's because the column feature is a map.

Is there any other way to do this grouping ?

I am using Spark version 3.2.2 and SQLContext, with scala language.

**EDIT** : **This is in the context of SPARK STRUCTURED STREAMING**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spark dataframe groupby multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771327/spark-dataframe-groupby-multiple-times)

Comment: No, I am trying to group by multiple columns (one of them contains a map), and get the row with the latest timestamp in each group.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. With a `groupBy("brand","original_timestamp","features", "weight").agg(max("arrival_timestamp")` is not enough? based on the input and output exepcted, looks like you only want to keep the row with the latest timestamp arrival when the rest of the columns are the same

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep the latest timestamp when the rest of the columns are the same (except the column "weight"). In other words, I would like to keep the latest weight.
But it seems that the group by doesn't accept the column "features" because it contains a map.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `map` type to some `string` type using `to_json` function and pass it in `Window.partitionBy` function. Check below sample solution.

```
scala> mdf.show(false)
+-----+------------------+------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|brand|original_timestamp|weight|arrival_timestamp      |features            |
+-----+------------------+------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|BR1  |1632899456        |4.0   |2023-08-09 17:12:24.002|{f1 -> 12, f2 -> 52}|
|BR1  |1632899456        |4.0   |2023-08-09 17:14:24.002|{f1 -> 42, f2 -> 12}|
|BR1  |1632899456        |2.0   |2023-08-09 17:46:24.002|{f1 -> 42, f2 -> 12}|
|BR3  |1632899155        |2.0   |2023-08-09 17:14:24.002|{f1 -> 72, f2 -> 50}|
|BR3  |1632899155        |9.0   |2023-08-09 17:20:24.002|{f1 -> 72, f2 -> 50}|
+-----+------------------+------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

scala> val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy($"brand",$"original_timestamp",to_json($"features").as("features")).orderBy(col("arrival_timestamp").desc)
windowSpec: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@10b34165

scala> mdf.withColumn("maxTs", first($"arrival_timestamp").over(windowSpec)).where($"maxTs" === $"arrival_timestamp").drop("maxTs").show(false)
+-----+------------------+------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|brand|original_timestamp|weight|arrival_timestamp      |features            |
+-----+------------------+------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|BR1  |1632899456        |4.0   |2023-08-09 17:12:24.002|{f1 -> 12, f2 -> 52}|
|BR1  |1632899456        |2.0   |2023-08-09 17:46:24.002|{f1 -> 42, f2 -> 12}|
|BR3  |1632899155        |9.0   |2023-08-09 17:20:24.002|{f1 -> 72, f2 -> 50}|
+-----+------------------+------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks ! As I am doing this in the context of Spark Structured Streaming, it seems that non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets. Do you have any idea on how to bypass this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that to_json has two significant functional drawbacks:

1. It does not order keys (not [option](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html) exists to do so)
2. It only supports string keys (json limitation, but seemingly not relevant to this question)

It also comes with performance impact, although not likely noticable in this case as you can probably ignore the results afterwards.

Why is key order important?

```scala
spark.sql("select map('b', 'b', 'a', 'a') amap, map('a', 'a', 'b', 'b') bmap").
      selectExpr("*", "to_json(amap) jamap", "to_json(bmap) jbmap").
      selectExpr("*", "(jamap = jbmap) same").
      show
```

yields:

```
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
|            amap|            bmap|            jamap|            jbmap| same|
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
|{b -> b, a -> a}|{a -> a, b -> b}|{"b":"b","a":"a"}|{"a":"a","b":"b"}|false|
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
```

Although the maps are the same, the column same above is false as the json representations are not the same.

In your case it seems enough to [sort via the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65932879/1028537) first then to_json but if there is an nesting of maps or you swap string keys for other types you'll need another solution.

In order to add generic comparison, group by etc. to maps, however deeply nested, I added [comparable_maps](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/sqlfunctions/#comparable_maps) to Quality.  The one known limitation is on intervals within the type which are also not comparable (and have different representations on different Spark versions).

```scala
com.sparkutils.quality.registerQualityFunctions()
sparkSession.sql("select map('b', 'b', 'a', 'a') amap, map('a', 'a', 'b', 'b') bmap").
      selectExpr("*", "comparable_maps(amap) camap", "comparable_maps(bmap) cbmap").
      selectExpr("*", "(camap = cbmap) same").
      show
```

yields:

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----+
|            amap|            bmap|           camap|           cbmap|same|
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----+
|{b -> b, a -> a}|{a -> a, b -> b}|[{a, a}, {b, b}]|[{a, a}, {b, b}]|true|
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks ! In my case, I only have (String -> String) maps. So I will sort by key before converting to JSON.